# Grant location permission in Runtime по нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Смотрел уроки по данной теме и там нашел вот этот код:

```
public abstract class AbsRuntimePermission extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SparseIntArray mErrorString;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mErrorString = new SparseIntArray();

    }

    public abstract void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode);

    public void requestAppPermissions(final String[]requestedPermissions, final int stringId, final int requestCode) {
        mErrorString.put(requestCode, stringId);

        int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        boolean showRequestPermissions = false;
        for(String permission: requestedPermissions) {
            permissionCheck = permissionCheck + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
            showRequestPermissions = showRequestPermissions || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission);
        }

        if (permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(showRequestPermissions) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), stringId, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AbsRuntimePermission.this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        for(int permission : grantResults) {
            permissionCheck = permissionCheck + permission;
        }

        if( (grantResults.length > 0) && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permissionCheck) {
            onPermissionsGranted(requestCode);
        } else {
            //Display message when contain some Dangerous permisson not accept
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), mErrorString.get(requestCode),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Наследую от этого класса `MainActivity` и в `onCreate()` прописываю это:

```
requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    },
                    R.string.permission_msg, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
```

При запуске приложения появляется SnackBar с кнопкой и по нажатии он всегда переходит в настройки приложения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как нибудь разрешить доступ к геолокации без перехода на какие либо настройки?
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Начиная с Android 6.0 были изменены требования к получению разрешений, а т.к. уровень разрешений `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`  относится к опасным, то другого способа их получить - нет.